# Linux: Connect to two different networks with same ip range

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, nat

GoPro cameras create a wifi hotspot when you turn on their wifi functionality. There is no way to make them use a different IP range, and I need to connect to multiple GoPros simultaneously (using multiple wireless interfaces).

The GoPro will be available at IP 10.5.5.9 on both networks.

How can I translate the IP addresses from wlan1 to a different range? E.g. make up adresses 10.5.5.* on wlan1 be available as 10.1.1.*?

This would allow me to access one GoPro at 10.1.1.9 and the other GoPro at 10.5.5.9.

Comment: Do they, at least, create a unique wifi ?

Comment: @frodeborli,You can use static route to do it when you have 2 different network.And You want to access to 2 different network.

Comment: Not answering your question, but you might also look at this [python](https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/GoProController) code that seems to *sequentially* handle several gopros via a single wifi device.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I don't have the option to test this really, so I'm bound to have some detail wrong, but essentially you'll need special routing to make some packets for address 10.5.5.9 to go out wlan1 and some other to go out wlan0 (I assume), and you'll need DNAT and SNAT rules to translate between 10.5.5.9 and 10.1.1.9.

The latter would be rules like the following:

```
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.1.1.9 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.5.5.9
# iptables -t nat -A INPUT -i wlan1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.1.9
```

For routing, I assume that at first 10.5.5.9 packets go out on wlan0. so you need an alternative routing table to kick in, for packets to 10.1.1.9 (which also get DNAT-ted). The table could be set up as follows

```
# ip route add table 26 dev wlan1
# ip route add table 26 10.5.5.9 dev wlan1
# ip rule add priority 10000 fwmark 26 table 26
```

The last rule makes table 26 be used for packets marked with 26, and that needs another rule:

```
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 10.1.1.9 -j MARK --set-mark 26
```

I assume that setup is done after having wlan1 and wlan0 up, and both having their addresses on 10.5.5.0/24. And that prior set up should have routing to direct 10.5.5.9 packets through wlan0 (thus rendering the wlan1 connection unused).

In this solution, the network paths are: packets to 10.1.1.9 first get marked, and secondly DNAT-ted to 10.5.5.9. The marking activates the routing table 26, which directs 10.5.5.9 packets to wlan1. And return packets are all SNAT-ted to be from 10.1.1.9.

Works in theory :-)